# Are the Increased Stat borg option’s listed maximums in Chromebook 2 the maximum you can buy or the maximum for the stat?

Tags: cyberpunk-2020

In the Full Borg options in Chromebook 2, the Increased Stat option says Reflex maximum is 15, Body maximum is 20 and MA is 25. Is that the maximum number of +1's you can buy up to, or the maximum that the stat can be boosted up to?

Comment: Wow. Context doesn't make that clear *at all.* Maybe a later book in the game line offers more information because *Chrome Book 2* certainly doesn't seem to! Curse you, gaming book from 1992!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the maximum STAT you can buy STARTING FROM ZERO, as it is stated:

- Reflex cost 2000eb **per** 1 point (Maximum stat is 15)
- MA cost 1500eb **per** 1 point (Maximum stat is 25)
- Body costs 1000eb **per** 1 point (Maximum stat is 20)
- Humanity cost is 2 **per** 1 point increase in any stat.

Your original stats are lost, because all your body is now the cyborg, you **don't add** these to your original **REF**, **MA** or **BOD**, so you have to design and pay your stats from scratch, so a basic 10/10/10 body would be:

- **REF 10**: 20.000 eb
- **MA 10**: 15.000 eb
- **BOD 10**: 10.000 eb
- **Humanity cost**: 30 sanity points

You can notice that the Full 'borg stats are fixed on stats for anyone, as it retains mental capabilities but fully replace your body, hence all your physical stats.

Also you can get the models on the book and calculate his cost based on these, if I remember well they fit those costs neatly, so in the end, these are the **MAX stats you'll ever reach**.

**EDIT:** You **CAN'T** get a Dragoon package with 20 **BOD** and then upgrade it 20 more for a total 40 **BOD**. <-- THIS IS WHAT CAN NOT BE DONE.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand you... if you went all out on an Alpha which has 12 BOD, you could pump it up to 32 BOD with this? Not up to a maximum of 20?

Comment: @Raktus I agree that this answer should state outright that, for example, *(Maximum 15)* should be read as *(Maximum +15)* if that's what the answer's trying to say. Further, I also agree that this answer would benefit greatly from using an example from the text. (And the answer would benefit from eliminating the word *clearly* — were it clear, the question wouldn't've been asked and at least 7 other users wouldn't've thought the question valid!)

Comment: NO! You can't go past the maximum if you boost an Alpha 12 BOD you can go up to 20 no more

Comment: In short, when you buy the full borg kit your REF, MA, and BOD are set to 0. Any previous changes to those stats are lost. You then buy the stats back up following the rules for the full borg kit (at the eb cost listed and up to the maximum listed). Whether mods installed after the full borg kit can increase those maximums depends on the nature of the mod (anything meant to improve a meat limb or organ would not work, cyber enhancements may or may not), but any preexisting ones are tossed in the trash with your old meat parts and no longer apply. That's the way I understand the answer, anyway.

Comment: That's correct @cpcodes